# Why is `terraform fmt` outputting a filename when it doesn't appear to have changed anything?

Tags: terraform

I have a file, A, committed into git.

If I do a `terraform fmt --check --recursive .` it outputs `A`.

However, if I then do a `git diff` I get blank output and `git status` reports no changes.

If I re-run `terraform fmt --check --recursive .` it again outputs `A`.

Any suggestions what's going wrong?

My understanding from https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/fmt.html
is that it will only output a filename if it has changed that file.

EXAMPLE

```
resource "aws_vpc" "test_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "192.168.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"
}
```

The issue is with this line: `instance_tenancy`. Looking at it in vi there are no odd characters that I can see.

```
Terraform v0.15.4
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.37.0
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? And what Terraform version are you using? What operating system are you running on?

Comment: example above. os etc above.

Comment: From the example, there is no problem with the `instance_tenancy` line. However, `fmt` would fix the issue with the previous line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-check` flag also implies `-write=false`.

From [Terraform doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/fmt.html):

> `-write=false` - Don't overwrite the input files. (This is implied by `-check` or when the input is STDIN.)